# Copy (update if exists) document from one collection to another

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to copy a document from one collection of mongodb to another collection (or update if exist) through java.

I don't want to append each field of existing collection and then insert to another. How can I do this?

Here are two collections, `temp` and `national`. `temp` has only one collection, which I have to copy to `national` or update if it exists.

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = db.getCollection("temp").find().iterator();
try {
    Document doc = new Document(cursor.next());
    Document new_doc = new Document("$set",doc);
    doc.append("booking_id",cursor.next().get("booking_id"));
    MongoCursor<Document>  cursor1 = db.getCollection("national").find(doc).iterator();
    Bson filter = Filters.eq("booking_id", args);
    Bson update = Filters.elemMatch("booking_id", filter);
    UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
    national.updateOne(filter, new_doc, options);
}
finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: so you mean replace B with A if exists, or create a new one if do not exists?

Comment: yes, where A is a document in collection "temp" and B is document in collection "national"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want replace Doc2 with Doc1 you can use replaceOne()

**replaceOne() replaces the first matching document in the collection that matches the filter, using the replacement document.**

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/

Comment: I was trying update method (with upsert:true option)